# What is the pythonic way to loop through two arrays at the same time?

Tags: python

If I have two arrays, of the same length - say `a` and `b`

`a = [4,6,2,6,7,3,6,7,2,5]`

`b = [6,4,6,3,2,7,8,5,3,5]`

normally, I would do this like so:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i] + b[i]
```

rather than something like this:

```
i=0
for number in a:
    print number + b[i]
    i += 1
```

because I prefer to be consistent with methods used.

I know of `zip`, but I never use it. Is this what `zip` was made for?

would

```
for pair in zip(a,b):
    print pair[0] + pair[1]
```

be the *pythonic* way to do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If the lists `a` and `b` are short, use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (as @Vincenzo Pii showed):

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x + y)
```

If the lists `a` and `b` are long, then use [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to save memory:

```
import itertools as IT
for x, y in IT.izip(a, b):
    print(x + y)
```

`zip` creates a list of tuples. This can be burdensome (memory-wise) if `a` and `b` are large.

`itertools.izip` returns an iterator. The iterator does not generate the complete list of tuples; it only yields each item as it is requested by the for-loop. Thus it can save you some memory.

In Python2 calling `zip(a,b)` on short lists is quicker than using `itertools.izip(a,b)`. But in Python3 note that `zip` returns an iterator by default (i.e. it is equivalent to `itertools.izip` in Python2).

---

Other variants of interest:

- [from future_builtin import zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip) -- if you wish to program with
  Python3-style `zip` while in Python2.
- [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) -- if `a` and `b` are of unequal length.

Comment: To make this complete, I'd also mention `future_builtins`.

Comment: So in zip in python3 is the same as itertools.izip? Or does it change depending on the size of the lists?

Comment: @will: Yes, `zip` in Python3 is the same as `itertools.izip` in Python2. (It does not change behavior with the size of the list.) To get the old `zip` behavior in Python3, use `list(zip(a,b))`.

Answer (score 11):

A possible solution is using `zip`, as you mentioned yourself, but slightly differently than how you wrote it in the question:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print x, y
```

Notice that the length of the list of tuples returned by `zip()` will be equal to the minimum between the lengths of `a` and `b`. This impacts when `a` and `b` are not of the same length.

Comment: This does look very familiar from various examples and documentation pages

Comment: That confirms it's pythonic :)!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `zip` you could use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), especially if speed is important and you have long arrays. Its much faster and once you're using numpy arrays you don't need a loop, and can just write:

```
print a + b
```

Graph showing averaged timings for summing different length lists using zip, izip, and numpy:
[image]

Comment: Yah i know about numpy. It's definitely applicable in this instance, but the example i gave was just a contrived one. What i really want it for is when you have two lists of objects, and you want to access the nth object of both.

It became apparent to me when i wanted to add a `hatch` pattern to `wedges` in a `matplotlib` piechart. The end use would be something like `for pattern, wedge in zip(patterns, wedges): wedge.set_hatch(pattern)`

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize a `while loop` to iterate over both arrays simultaneously.

```
i,j = 0,0
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    print(a[i] + n[j])
    i += 1 
    j += 1
```

**Note that** this loop is repeated for the **shortest number** of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Offering this answer for completeness since `numpy` has been discussed in another answer, and it is often useful to pair values together from higher ranked arrays.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293953/2437514) works great for any sequence/array of rank 1. However, if the sequence is of multiple levels (such as a `numpy` array of rank 2 or more, but also such as in a `list` of `list`s, or `tuple` of `tuple`s), one needs to iterate through each rank. Below is an example with a 2D `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b = np.array([list('abc'), list('pdq'), list('xyz')])
c = np.array([[frobnicate(aval, bval) for aval, bval in zip(arow, brow)] for arow, brow in zip(a, b)])
```

And the same concept will work for any set of two dimensional nested sequences of the same shape:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [list('abc'), list('pdq'), list('xyz')]
c = [[frobnicate(aval, bval) for aval, bval in zip(arow, brow)] for arow, brow in zip(a, b)]
```

If one or both of the nested sequences has "holes" in it, use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to fill in the holes (the fill value defaults to `None` but can be specified):

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zipl
a = [[], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] # empty list in the first row
b = [list('abc'), list('pdq'), []] # empty list in the last row
c = [[frobnicate(aval, bval) for aval, bval in zipl(arow, brow)] for arow, brow in zipl(a, b)]
```